# Lightning Accordion: changing the arrow location

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

In [Lightning Accordion tag](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/) I need to change the location of the expand/collapse arrow so instead of it being in the left side of the title (aka the Accordion summary), it should be in the right side. 
Is there any way to accomplish that? or maybe another component which would achieve the same result?

Comment: Do you use the lightning:accordion component or did you only use the lightning design system?

Comment: I'm using the lightning:accordion component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the css order property and apply that property to the children like this:

```
.THIS .slds-accordion__summary-heading > button > span {
    order: 1;
}

.THIS .slds-accordion__summary-heading > button > lightning-primitive-icon {
    order: 2;
}
```

Gives you something like:

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks! Only issue is that I loose the space between the Title and the arrow.

Comment: Figured that out. Add this to the 2nd item in order:
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 10px;